# Simulate Screen

Tags: c

Is there any way to make a Cinema (or any type of) Display in C?

I have seen some code but there is almost no documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Implementing IOFramebuffer, like EWFrameBuffer etc. does is the way to go for creating a graphics driver. There is a little bit of breakage in various versions, but it's possible to get things working nicely, including retina resolutions, with some trial and error. Hardware acceleration is separate:

Older versions of OSX used the `IOGraphicsAcceleratorInterface` for 2D acceleration if your driver provided a CFPlugin bundle that implemented it together with your kext.

I haven't figured it out on Yosemite; it seems that it doesn't use 2D acceleration. To make things worse, software rendering performance is also considerably worse on Yosemite than on previous releases. I encourage anyone who is affected by this (headless mac mini, OS X in VMs, virtual displays, etc.) to file a Radar with Apple. I have already done so, but the more people complain, the more likely it is that they'll do something about it.

The 3D acceleration (OpenGL) APIs are private on all versions. I'm not aware of any 3rd party implementation of them, open source or otherwise, unless you count the Intel/AMD/nVidia GPU drivers, which seem to be developed in cooperation between Apple and the relevant company.

**UPDATE:** It turns out that Yosemite's WindowServer limits frame rates to about 8fps *unless* your IOFramebuffer driver correctly implements vertical blank interrupts. So if your driver doesn't already do so, implement the methods `registerForInterruptType()`, `unregisterInterrupt` and `setInterruptState` work with interrupt type `kIOFBVBLInterruptType`, and generate a callback every time you finish emitting a full image. The details of this will depend on your device (or lack thereof). This doesn't solve the hardware acceleration and rendering glitch issues, but it does at least improve performance somewhat (at the cost of higher CPU load).

Comment: You need to simulate a display with >= 150dpi (so pixels divided by reported physical dimensions), and you need to set the `kDisplayModeValidForHiResFlag` flag on the display mode in question. I also had to provide a valid EDID or System Preferences for that display would glitch out, but that was on Mountain Lion, so they might have fixed that.